# Maximizing a sequence of items under order and pairwise restriction

Tags: algorithms, optimization, combinatorics

Suppose I have a number of items $\{A ... Z$} which are ordered accordingly. Each item has an associated weight, for example $W_A$. Between all items, there's a criterion $c$ which determines whether they fit together. So if $A$ and $B$ don't fit together, maybe $A$ and $C$ do, and then the next fitting neighbour from $C$ would have to be found.

The goal is to find a chain $S$ among these items that has the items in the original order, all subsequent items meet $c$ and that maximizes the sum $\sum_{i \in S} W_i$. A naive approach would completely explode in runtime I suppose. Does anyone have a way in mind to liken it to a solved problem?

Comment: Try dynamic programming.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of the knapsack problem, but it's not quite the same ...

Comment: Do you need every pair in the solution to satisfy $c$, or just adjacent ones? In the former case, this is essentially max clique.

Comment: Only between two adjacent elements! Thanks, I'm gonna look into that!